# Providing a service from within SBT to the Scala compiler

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-macros

I have a Scala macro which (sometimes) needs to talk to an external service. We can assume that this service is hosted on the same machine. Starting this service is very expensive (~ 3 minutes on first run, ~ 5 seconds on subsequent runs on the same machine), which is why it should be "pooled" in some way. Just querying the service is very cheap. The service offers a Scala API.

The naive solution would be to add the library to the compiler classpath and do something like

```
val instance = service.start(...)
val tree =
  if (instance.query(...))
     q"""new meep { ... }"""
  else
     context.abort("no can do")
instance.teardown()
tree
```

Naturally, this is very slow if there are many invocations of the macro.

My idea would be to start the service in SBT and provide it to the Scala compiler in some way. This poses some interesting questions.

1. How to pass the startup parameters?
   Potential solution: Create an SBT plugin which defines some `SettingKeys`.
2. How to start the service?
   Potential solution: In the SBT plugin, define a custom `command` which checks if the service is already alive, and if not, starts it given the settings. But where would it put the reference to the instance? In the `State`, using an `AttributeKey`? [0]
3. How to tell the Scala compiler about the service?
   Potential solution: No idea. This would probably entail some sort of "shim" of the API which can be put on the compiler classpath and internally communicates with SBT.

If it helps, assume the service is a "database" where the macro checks whether a specific implicit inference is "allowed". SBT would call systemd/... to start the "database" daemon.

[0] Side note: Since the macro doesn't always need to talk to the service, it would also make sense to have SBT start it on demand (unless that complicates matters).

Comment: Are you allowed a compiler plugin? How about good old fashioned system properties?

Comment: Compiler plugin is not an option. I don't understand how system properties would help – they allow me to pass in strings, not arbitrary objects.

Comment: but if you get an arbitrary string can you not use it as, e.g. the jdbc connection?

Comment: As I said, imagining this service as the database is a little simplistic. In reality, I need to expose the Scala API to the macro. Or else, implement some other communication layer myself.